# XSLT passing two parameters in URL with ColdFusion

Tags: xml, xslt, coldfusion, parameters, hyperlink

I am trying to pass two parameters through URL in XSLT file by using ColdFusion.

This is my XSLT code:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Actors: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/movies/movie/actors/actor/name"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
      <xsl:element name="a">
          <xsl:attribute name="href">actor_details.cfm?movieID=<xsl:value-of select="../../../@movieID"/>&amp;actorID=<xsl:value-of select="../@actorID"/></xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:element name="br" />
</xsl:template>
```

This is my actor_details.cfm file

```
<cfset MyXmlFile = Expandpath("test.xml")>
<cffile action="READ" variable="xmlInput"  file="#MyXmlFile#">
<cfset MyXslFile = Expandpath("actor_details.xsl")>
<cffile action="READ" variable="xslInput"  file="#MyXslFile#">

<cfset xslParam = StructNew() >
<cfset xslParam["movieID"] = "#url.movieID#" >

<cfset xmlOutput = XMLTransform(xmlInput, xslInput, xslParam )>
<!--- data is output --->
<cfcontent type="text/html" reset="yes">
<cfoutput>#xmloutput#</cfoutput>
```

And this is my actor_details.xsl file

```
<xsl:param name="movieID"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <title>Actor details</title>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/movies/movie[@movieID=$movieID]/actors/actor[@actorID=$actorID]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="actor">
    <xsl:text>Name: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    <xsl:element name="br"/>
    <xsl:text>Age: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="age"/>
    <xsl:element name="br"/>
</xsl:template>
```

So based on the movieID and actorID passed through the URL, the actor_details page should display the actor's name and age. I am very new to ColdFusion and I can't figure out how to receive parameters passed through the URL with ColdFusion. I get unexpected error on the actor_details.cfm page.

I think the problem lies somewhere in actor_details.cfm page, but I just can't figure out what it is.

My XML file:

```
<movie movieID="1">
    <actors>
        <actor actorID="1"> 
            <name>Bob</name>
            <age>23</age>
        </actor>

        <actor actorID="2"> 
            <name>Jack</name> 
            <age>25</age>
        </actor>

        <actor actorID="3"> 
            <name>James</name>
            <age>38</age>
        </actor>
    </actors>   
</movie>

<movie movieID="2">
    <actors>
        <actor actorID="1"> 
            <name>Mike</name>
            <age>19</age>
        </actor>

        <actor actorID="2"> 
            <name>Daniel</name>
            <age>29</age>
        </actor>

        <actor actorID="3"> 
            <name>Phil</name> 
            <age>41</age>
        </actor>
    </actors>   
</movie>
```

Comment: Do a <cfdump var="#url#"> on your action page.

Comment: ok I've done that and it displays "struct actorID 1, MovieID 1" for the first actor. If I click on the other names it displays struct properly based on their actorID and movieID. so it seems to be working, but I still get unexpected error below. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Also if you don't have robust debugging output and logging, turn it on in administrator of your dev server, it will help you tremendously.  Make sure to select the application, session, cgi scopes for output.  It will slow your pages down but you only turn it on for your IP and dev server only.

Comment: I'm using university's server and unfortunately I don't have administrator rights to change debugging output.

Comment: @alex what line gives the error? If you can dump `#url.movieID#` then the issue has to be somewhere else.

Comment: *unfortunately I don't have administrator rights* As an alternative, wrap the whole code block in a `cftry/cfcatch`. Then dump the error inside the cfcatch block: ie `<cfdump var="#cfcatch#">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by adding `<cfset xslParam["actorID"] = URL.actorID >` to my CFM file and `<xsl:param name="actorID"/>` to my XSL file.

Comment: modified to remove unnecessary # signs

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about URL variables.  The URL is one of CF's variable scopes and can be accessed like:

```
 <cfset myvar = #URL.actorid# >
```

Of course you don't have to use the # signs on the right but since you're just learning it's a good way to identify your CF vars.

Here is a link to CF 9 docs and CF's built in [variable scopes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec173d0-7ffb.html).

Comment: So instead of <cfset xslParam["movieID"] = "#url.movieID#" >, I can just put <cfset myvar = #URL.movieID# >? Since I'm using xslParam, I'm not quite sure how I can use this code instead of the original one

Comment: @Alex You would still want to use `<cfset xslParam["movieID"] = url.movieID>` The `##` are not necessary. This answer doesn't help much.

Comment: @Alex - Best to start off on the right foot. Do not use # signs that way. They are completely unnecessary. While it will not cause a syntax error, it is usually considered poor coding and even Adobe [discourages the usage of extraneous # signs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fc3.html). If you are new to CF, you might find this link helpful: [Bamboozled by Pound Sign Decisions](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2011/2/10/when.do.i.use.pound.signs)

Comment: Hmm, pretty sure it says they're not needed but thanks for clearing that up @Leigh.  In truth, Adobe doesn't discourage their use at all and it's not poor coding practice when used correctly (mine was not but I thought I explained why)...in fact they are required in certain circumstances.  They are 'use only when required' because there was a point when they were required use.  Some old CF developers will still use them thinking they have to...please delete your comment because it is incorrect information.

Comment: @JustAguy - Huh...? When an answer has related comments, please do not make modifications that destroy the context of those comments.  **Your** original answer (which you later modified) encouraged this guy to use `#` signs that were not needed: *"Just Aguy wrote: Of course you don't have to use the # signs on the right but since you're just learning it's a good way to identify your CF vars."* As I said, using extraneous `#` signs is really a poor coding practice, and not something to recommend. Especially to someone just learning the language. Let us encourage people to learn the right way.